# Declared the same varible twice

Tags: java

I'm making a text-adventure game, where i have a method for adding items to certain rooms in the game. and i have accidently declared the same method twice.

```
 ArrayList<Item> items = player.getCurrentposition().getItems();
        if(items.size() > 0)
        {

            for (Item item : player.getCurrentposition().getItems()) 
            {}
            io.put("\n\nYou've stumbled upon an item! Do you want to pick it up?\nInput 0 if room contains 1 item, "
                    + "and if the room contains 2 items input either 0 or 1, depending on which you wish to pick up" + player.getCurrentposition().getItems());
 //the first method used to loop through the found items, int pickUp = io.getInteger(0, player.getCurrentposition().getItems().size());

            player.getInv().add(player.getCurrentposition().getItems().get(pickUp));
            System.out.println("You picked up the following item(s): " + player.getCurrentposition().getItems());
            ArrayList<Item> it = player.getCurrentposition().getItems();
            for (Item object : it) 
            {
                player.addToInv(object);
                if(object instanceof Weapon)
                {
                    ((Weapon)object).addToPlayerDamage(player);
                }
                else if(object instanceof Potion)
                {
                    ((Potion)object).applyPotion(player);
                }
            }
            //System.out.println(player.getInv().size()); <-- used to check
            player.getCurrentposition().getItems().remove(pickUp);              

            io.put("here is some stuff..:\n");

            for (Item item : items) 
            {
                io.put(item.getName()+"\n");
            io.put("\n\nYou've stumbled upon an item! Do you want to pick it up?\nInput 0 if room contains 1 item, "
                   + "and if the room contains 2 items input either 0 or 1, depending on which you wish to pick up" + player.getCurrentposition().getItems());

            }
            ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList();
            options.add("Nothing");

            for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
                options.add(i+1+ ": " + items.get(i).getName());
            }
            options.add("All");

            int pickUp = io.select("Here are the options you can chose from  +", options, "");
//here is the second int pickUp, which is used to select the items, that the        user wants and add them to the users inventory. 
            if(pickUp == 0){
                //nothing
            } else if(pickUp == options.size()-1){
                //all
            } else {
                player.getInv().add(player.getCurrentposition().getItems().get(pickUp - 1));
                player.getCurrentposition().getItems().remove(pickUp - 1);
            } 
        }
```

the int pickUp is declared twice, but i don't know if i can just rename pickUp to something else. The first time i declare pickUp in order to let the player pickup an item, the second time i will give the olayer to chose if he wants to collect the item or not.

Can i rename the second int PickUp to something else, like chosePickUp, and have the same results without the error.

Comment: try and see. just make sure you change the name everywhere you meant to use that one

Comment: _i have accidently declared the same method twice_ You declared the same variable twice.

Comment: sutltuske, thank you for your answer. I have looked at the code, and i can't decide if i should just rename the second method, and i will get the same answer

Comment: that's not up to you to "decide", just rename it. as it is now, it won't compile anyway.

Comment: How come it won't compile after i rename it?

Comment: it won't now, since you have two members with the same name.

Comment: Where does the first `pickUp` get defined? Is it a class member? A parameter to the function? A local var? Anyway, it doesn't look too difficult to just rename the 2nd one.

Comment: @Johnny Mopp i tried to add a comment where i defined it, however it was probably not very clear.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp

here is the definition:
    "int pickUp = io.getInteger(0, player.getCurrentposition().getItems().size());"

if the player is in a room with an item it is used. 
Then there is an ArrayList of 'items', from the room, which is looped through.

Comment: It's still not clear. You can't declare the same variable with the same name in the same scope. Do some reading on [variable scope](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+variable+scope)

Comment: You are using `player.getCurrentposition().getItems()` in many different ways in that code ... from the beginning you have the reference in `items` ....

Comment: yes @AxelH what is the point about your comment? is that a fundamental flaw or what do you think?

Comment: It made me think you write your code without knowing what you were doing ... `for (Item item : player.getCurrentposition().getItems()) {}` you have an for-loop that do nothing, then you get the same list in `ArrayList<Item> it = player.getCurrentposition().getItems();`. This is unreadable. You could start playing with `item` and `it`, both are the same list ... why ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are both type Integer. Why not try to not re declare it as an integer the second time you use it. Unless you are storing the initial value and recomputing the new value while needing both.

Second option is if you are needing both then renaming the second variable should not affect much. The first variable seems to take the item and its size; where as the second gives you an option and stores it. I do not see an issue with renaming the second variable based on this segment of code. Make sure that if you do rename it that the following if statements are changed as well.

EDIT:
Yeah while reading your code once more I think you should rename your second variable and call it something like pickedupItem. I am assuming that 0 means he ignored the item, second if statement i don't know and third if statement he picked up the item and its being allocated in the inventory. If you can clear up what the second if statement does then I may be able to help a little more.